# How do I rewrite two branches of code that only differ in one variable's type, in a Java 8 functional style?

Tags: java, functional-programming, refactoring, option-type

I want to rewrite the following logic in a functional style, *i.e.* a one-liner using `map`, `filter`, `ifPresent`, `orElse`, `orElseGet`, `orElseThrow`, etc.

```
String id;
if (entity.legacyIndicator().isPresent()) { // field is an Optional<Foo>
  if (entity.legacyId().isPresent()) { // field is an Optional<Long>
    id = entity.legacyId().toString(); // e.g. id = '01234567'
  } else {
    throw new IOException("No ID found.");
  }
} else {
  if (entity.newId().isPresent()) { // field is an Optional<UUID>
    id = entity.newId().toString(); // e.g. id = '01234567-89ab-cdef-0123-456789abcdef'
  } else {
    throw new IOException("No ID found.");
  }
}
```

The main trouble for me is that `legacyId()` and `newId()` are different types. How do I "unify" both branches given that I, as the programmer, know that they both share `isPresent()` and `toString()`, though not sharing an actual interface?

I will edit this question with my best attempt, shortly, as I'm still working out what I can. But I'm totally stumped on unifying the branches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, not really clean, but i would go for something like

```
    public String getId(Test.Entity entity) throws Throwable {
    return entity.legacyIndicator()
        .map(o -> (Optional) entity.legacyId())
        .orElseGet(() -> (Optional) entity.newId())
        .orElseThrow(() -> new IOException("No ID found."))
        .toString();
}
```

Here some Junit test to validate the execution

```
@org.junit.Test
public void test() throws Throwable {
    Entity entity = new Entity();

    entity.legacyIndicator = Optional.empty();
    final UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
    entity.newId = Optional.of(uuid);

    String id = getId(entity);
    Assert.assertEquals(uuid.toString(), id);


    entity = new Entity();

    entity.legacyIndicator = Optional.of(Boolean.TRUE);
    entity.newId = Optional.of(uuid);
    entity.legacyId = Optional.of("SomeId");
    id = getId(entity);

    Assert.assertEquals("SomeId", id);
}

@org.junit.Test(expected = IOException.class)
public void testExceptionLegacy() throws Throwable {
    Entity entity = new Entity();

    entity.legacyIndicator = Optional.of(Boolean.TRUE);
    entity.legacyId = Optional.empty();
    String id = getId(entity);
}

@org.junit.Test(expected = IOException.class)
public void testExceptionNew() throws Throwable {
    Entity entity = new Entity();

    entity.legacyIndicator = Optional.empty();
    entity.legacyId = Optional.empty();
    entity.newId = Optional.empty();
    String id = getId(entity);
}

class Entity {
    Optional<Boolean> legacyIndicator;
    Optional<String> legacyId;
    Optional<UUID> newId;

    Optional<Boolean> legacyIndicator() {
        return legacyIndicator;
    }

    Optional<UUID> newId() {
        return newId;
    }

    Optional<String> legacyId() {
        return legacyId;
    }

}
```

Comment: Ah, `Optional<Object>`! Why didn't I think of that. I come from C++ and was trying to figure out Java unions or something. Thank you!

Comment: Darn. I realized that `Object::toString` is generic and won't use `UUID::toString`. Maybe there really is just no way around this, huh. Still, learned something from your use of `map` plus `orElseGet`.

Comment: Well it's just a cast, and the real object behind is an UUID, and the toString method executed will be the one from UUID not the one from Object

Comment: Oh! I thought for some reason the cast would destroy polymorphism... let me try it out... Hm, I actually get an error at the cast, `error: incompatible types: Optional<UUID> cannot be converted to Optional<Object>`

Comment: Hey andrew, i've updated the answer with a Junit test case working fine :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it, but let's not have "1-liner" as a requirement to avoid obfuscation.  A type than can hold both `Optional<String>` and `Optional<UUID>` is `Optional<?>`:

```
boolean legacy = entity.legacyIndicator().isPresent();  // weird use of Optional  
                                                        // shouldn't it be a boolean?

Optional<?> optId = legacy ? entity.legacyId() : entity.newId();

String id = optId.orElseThrow(() -> new IOException("ID not found")).toString();
```

Alternatively, you can do `toString` inside the `Optional` chain, if you find that clearer:

```
String id = optId.map(Object::toString).orElseThrow(...);
```

Now, you can combine it all into a 1-liner if that's what you want:

```
String id = (entity.legacyIndicator().isPresent() ? entity.legacyId() : entity.newId())
        .orElseThrow(() -> new IOException("ID not found"))
        .toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Because I could not cast to `Optional<Object>` as @Vyncent suggested, I ended up having to keep the branches separate:

```
String id = entity.legacyIndicator().isPresent()
            ? entity.legacyId().orElseThrow(() -> new IOException("No ID found.")).toString()
            : entity.newId().orElseThrow(() -> new IOException("No ID found.")).toString();
```

From the research I've done, it's not really possible to have a "wildcard" type without actually creating a generic. Open to ideas though!